# How do i get separate field in array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get separate field in array, I have array and some fields but I need single fields how can get below I given my code and out put of data(print_r) please how can I do this one, I'm new in **php**.
I want only for 'code' field only how can I get...

print_r() I'm getting this output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [code] => kg1 [name] => Kindergarden [status] => 1 [craeteddate] => 2022-02-03 17:33:05 )
```

My php code:

```
$data['classes'] = $this->enquiryform_model->get_class();

$class_code = $data['classes']['code'];
```

Comment: as you can there is another array inside $data['class'] which has 'code' you need to do this. `$code = $data['class'][0]; $code['code']`

Comment: Please refer to example #7 on the PHP documentation page for [Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 2):

you have two arrays. 1 inside another. So to get the `code` you need to do this.

```
  <?php
    $data['classes'] = array( 0 => array( 'id' => 1, 'code' => 'kg1', 'name' => 'Kindergarden', 'status' => 1, 'craeteddate' => '2022-02-03 17:33:05' ));
    $class_code = $data['classes'][0]['code'];
    echo $class_code;
    echo "\n";
    $class_code = $data['classes'][0];
    echo $class_code['code'];
?>
```

Here is the working [example](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xsctmd4s)